# tortoise svn merge bug fix in branch into trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to know what is the right way to merge a part of a branch into the trunk.

Assume that an older version of our product is in a branch, and I wrote a fix in that branch. Now, I want to merge this fix into the trunk.

I don't want to simply merge the branch into the trunk, because the trunk is quite different from the branch, and I don't want to "mess" with other things beside my fix.

How can I merge only the files (or folders) I wrote the fix ???

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Didn't you upload the fix in a separate commit?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, yes I did... Does it mean I can merge only the specific revision?

Comment: If you only need that revision, it's the obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merge changes from single revision in branch into trunk. Read `svn help merge`, about 2-nd form of merge, "cherry-pick merge"

In order to merge only changes from revision N from branch into trunk, perform in trunk's WC

`svn merge -c N URL/OF/BRANCHES/branch`

Answer (score 1):

You simply just merge the subdirectory you want :
if your project url is :
/project
you have eg
/project/trunk
/project/branches/branche01
if you want to merge subdirectory test only do that :
select /project/branches/branche01/test and merge to /project/trunk/test 
(or vice et versa)